# Frequency/amplitude modulation and SNR

Tags: noise, signal, signal-processing, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

I read (for instance [here](http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~kkleung/Communications2_2009/Lecture5.pdf)) that FM modulation is less affected by noise than AM modulation.

But I don't understand conceptually the reason for that: why is the SNR with frequency modulation higher than the SNR with amplitude modulation?

Comment: Re-read page 3 of the PDF you linked to.

Comment: @JRE: That's just a bunch of hand-waving. Doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: FM responds to FM and rejects AM modulation or superposition of noise. To some extent due to CNR to SNR demodulator improvement factor using more BW on carrier than Audio ( depending on band,subband). Also Lightning and engine noise does not reach 100MHz band ( highly attenuated). The real difference is due to the detectors. AM uses linear amplitude detectors ad FM uses linear freq mixers  (multipliers) and often PLL demodulation of carrier shift

Comment: Carson’s rule for wideband FM means there is a log effect of CNR/SNR improvement not possible in AM. Due to delta f/f >>1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is electrical engineering, but very specific – chances are high that https://signals.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate place to ask this. (recommending migration there)

Comment: @MarcusMüller If it doesn't get a good response here, then lets migrate it

Comment: I think this only holds true for 'percieved' noise in audio systems - not actual SNR levels of demodulated signals (and thus BER), given the same bandwidth, information rate and power levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal to noise goes as you'd expect, but in FM it's rather more subtle.

Let's say a transmission has white noise added to it in transit. That noise is uncorrelated to the signal, so half of it looks like AM (in phase with the carrier) and half of it looks like PM (phase modulation).

If the want to improve the SNR due to AM, then we can increase the carrier power of our transmitter. This gives us a linear improvement in SNR at the receiver, at the cost of real transmitted power. This is measured in watts, and so money for bigger transmitters, more power for them etc. If the interference is from natural sources, then this works. If the interference is from other transmitters further way, then 'everybody shouting louder' does not work.

If we want to improve SNR due to PM, then we can increase the carrier *deviation* of our transmitter. It costs no more in watts to send a signal that has +/- 10 radians deviation than one that has +/- 1 radian deviation, however the first one will have 20dB better SNR. You [don't get owt for nowt](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2013/12/eight-yorkshire-sayings-will-baffle-americans), and the cost of increasing the deviation power of the transmitter is that you can cram fewer wide deviation transmitters into any given bandwidth than AM transmitters.

Answer (score 0):

In a radio receiver, noise will generally appear as variations in the amplitude of the signal, and will be processed by the AM demodulator in the same way as the desired signal, so will be heard by the user.

In an FM receiver, the received signal is limited or clipped to remove amplitude variations (such as noise), and the FM demodulator will generally ignore any amplitude variations that get to it, so the noise on the initial signal will not be heard by the user.

Comment: And what about phase noise? Why is it less than amplitude noise? In theory it will affect very much the FM signals

Comment: random-phase noise is well-modeled with 50% of the noise power being AM, and the other 50% of power being PM which modulates the zero-crossing timings.

Comment: So is the advantage of FM the fact that it sees only the second one, while AM sees both?

Answer (score 0):

IN A VERY SIMPLIFIED WORLD. 
It is easier to "segragate" noise on the frequency domain because [white] noice is relative small across the frequency spectrum compared to the carrier sinal. Hense, you only pay attention to the frequency of the signal with the highest power, and track it. So at the end, noise *adds-up* in a non-desctructive way on your FM signal because it does NOT interfere with your tracking [ or at least, as long as your carrier's power is much higher than the noise's power].